# WiX 3.7: What is the right way to install a Windows service for a graceful upgrade and seamless uninstall?

Tags: windows-services, wix, wix3.7

Okay, I know how to use WiX to deploy a service, but I'm trying to solve the following dilemma. I want to preserve service configuration (e.g. log on credentials, etc) on major upgrades (so that user does not have to redefine the service settings). For this purpose, inside of InstallExecuteSequence, I use:

```
<DeleteServices>NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</DeleteServices>
```

I have the *ServiceControl*'s *Stop* attribute set to *both*. But what happens is that when I uninstall the app, if the service is runnning, I get the following warning:

*"The setup must update files or services that cannot be updated while the system is running. If you choose to continue, a reboot will be required to complete the setup."*

If I choose to continue and do not reboot, both the service and all app files get deleted, so this message seems totally bogus. If I manually stop the service before running the uninstaller, the warning does not appear.

Am I doing something wrong? What do I need to do to avoid this warning, while making sure that the service does not get deleted (and recreated) on major upgrade?

Comment: did u find solution?

Comment: Oh, man, this was  a long time ago, so do not remember, but this is what I see in the product WIX file:

Comment: <InstallExecuteSequence>
  !-- Do not delete Windows service configuration on upgrades. -->
  <DeleteServices>NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</DeleteServices>
  <InstallServices>NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED</InstallServices>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

Comment: Let me know if this works. I'll add it to the answers (or you can do it too).

Answer (score 0):

Well, good question,
as I understand, the problem is that services are not stopped, after you take care of DeleteServices, which seems to be odd, since the order of execution sequence is:

```
* StopServices
• DeleteServices
• RemoveFiles
• InstallFiles
• InstallServices
• StartServices
```

I would try this:

```
<DeleteServices After="StopServices" Before="RemoveFiles">NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</DeleteServices>
<InstallServices>NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</InstallServices>
```

but for the actual problem, this seems a little bit fishy, and what I would do, is create all the necessary registry keys/values to keep information about registry and not ASK it again for upgrading the product. You can then later pass that information again to services, and don't have to mess with your setup(this is pretty easy with properties, component conditions, registrySearch).

What if you want to add new services on upgrade? 
Ps, you can create new user, assign him privileges on installation, and login with that user for service. I understand there are more to remember, but nothing too complicated.

Comment: Hmmmm... The DeleteServices element does not seem to have After or Before attributes. The only supported attributes are Sequence and Suppress. I checked the MSI file in Orca, and the StopServices action has a sequence number 1900, while DeleteServices and RemoveFiles are 2000 and 3600 respectively, so it all looks fine from the sequence perspective.

Answer (score 0):

One technique would be to use a modified version of the [remember property pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern).  You'd want to add some encryption though.

The problem is MSI was designed to own definition of the configuration.  If the configuration changes, one of them has to win.  MSI handles this well for text/config files (  user data is preserved via creation date and modification date comparisons ) but for things like services there is no check.

Now if someone changes the service credentials the remember property will be used and it'll get changed back.

a tricky problem with no real solutions sometimes.   One approach is to always install as NetworkService or SYSTEM and change the design of your application to be ok with these credentials and profiles. (Simplify the problem.)

Comment: Right, but there are cases when SYSTEM or other built-in account would not work (e.g. when the service needs to use DPAPI encryption with user store, or access to Active Directory, or connect to a database server or a web service using integrated Windows authentication, etc).

Comment: And moving into the remember property pattern position for storing sensitive data (like account password) raises more serious questions than the problem I'm trying to solve in the first place (e.g. how do you encrypt it? where do you store encryption keys? how do you protect encryption keys? what if password for account changes and the user updates the log on info in the services control panel? but this info would not be known to the MSI? etc).

Comment: NetWorkService uses the AD computer account and you can grant that object access to other network resources.  Windows Installer is lacking in this area so you have to figure something out.  Just no-oping the standard actions doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Sure, but in most cases, if you deploy an enterprise app, you would not run a Windows service that access some sort of privileged resources as a NetworkServices account due to InfoSec restrictions. Normally, a generic AD account (with define life cycle, auditing, etc) would be used in this case. Regardless, what I'm saying is that in certain cases, running a windows service as a built-in account is not an option (if it were, it would be silly not to use it).